# Difference between 搂抱, 喂抱, 拥抱, 抱抱?

Tags: difference, word

What's the difference between :

> 搂抱 (I guess this one refers to hugging/cuddling in general)
>
> 喂抱 (I tried to look for this word and a lot of pictures of mother hugging their babies appeared as a result. So I'm guessing this one is used mostly for parents hugging/cuddling with her kids)
>
> 拥抱 (I also tried to look for this one and it's said that it's hugging/cuddling because of love and friendship)
>
> 抱抱 (I guess this one has the feeling that the action of hugging happens momentarily)

???

> Which one between 搂抱 and 拥抱 is more commonly used to refer to hugging/cuddling between lovers?
>
> Which one can be used to refer to hugging/cuddling with your pets?

I don't know and I'm not sure if my guesses are correct though. Really looking forward to your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

搂抱 is more sexually oriented
拥抱  is more emotionally oriented.
Here are some examples:

他搂抱着美女又是摸又是吻。（He's grabbing the beauty in his arm to touch and kiss.)

不敢相信女神搂抱着我热情的吻我（Can't believe the Goddess is hugging me and kissing me passionately.)

他拥抱着突然出现在他面前多年不见的妻子哭了起来。(He grabbed his wife who he hasn't seen in year and cried.)

母亲看到拿到冠军的孩子激动的拥抱着他哭了。(The mother who just witnessed his child becoming the champion hugged him in tears.)

本以为被抛弃的我看到女神的归来感动的拥抱着她说道：“我错了,我永远不要和你分开啦”。 (Me, who though being abandoned, saw the arrival of the Goddess, is deeply moved and hold her and say :"I'm sorry， I'll never leave you again."

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! It helps me clear out my confusion!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think 喂抱 is a word. Let me tell you a hack I found out myself. Whenever you have questions about the difference of words, you can do google image search and the result will tell you the slight difference among them.

1. 摟抱 is more about the intimacy of man and woman, and it's more common in the form of 摟摟抱抱.

   As you can see here, the results are mostly a man and a woman.
   [image: loubao]
2. 擁抱 is more about friends or family, but can also be used for couples.

   As you can see here, the results can be between same-sex, friends, people with large age difference or couples.
   [image: yongbao]
3. 抱抱 is informal, colloquial. More commonly used among couples to 撒嬌 (this word is hard to translate, basically IMO it means showing affection for someone and wants the other to do the same), but can also be used with anyone as a form of reduplication of 抱, e.g. 我抱抱他，安慰他。

   As you can see here, it's mostly used by couples. And often you see 給我抱抱 (exact example of 撒嬌)
   [image: baobao]
4. 抱 is the most general. This can be used for anyone. It just means hug.

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you for the answer and the hack! Anyway, I have tried to google each word as well but still can't really differentiate them! // anyway, I found 喂抱 in the dictionary :( maybe this word isn't commonly used/no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

I thought 抱抱 was mostly a children's term, since I've seen it often in made-for-kids contexts. (The TV show *Ni hao, Kai-lan* often has characters exclaim 抱抱 while hugging each other...and there's a popular song in which children plead for parents' attention, including the line 爱我你就抱抱我.)  Did I get the wrong impression?